# 3rd Party Library for chat with syncing to other device

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, openfire

I am working on chat application. I have chat syncing option like skype. suppose I am logged in Device A and I have done chat from this device. now when I logged in Device B at that time all the chat history will be synced in device B.

Problem with `XMPP`

I have 4 types of chat person to person, person to network, person to business and person to group. In xmpp we cant differentiate the type of chat, as in out local database we have a type field. and I guess in xmpp server database there is no type field to identify the type of chat. so I am looking for 3rd party API for chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XMPP, you can use the specification [Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

use this  https://www.twilio.com/ .this is gives you SDK. Twilio provide service of sms and chatting